# Email each account their own pdf report gets run time error 3265

Tags: vba, loops, email, ms-access, recordset

Please see code below that returns a run-time error 3265 due to the line:
strTo = !email_address1

however, if i changed it to 
strTo = !AccountNumber it will populate in the outlook email To: line properly but i need the email address, not the account number - do i need to define email_address1?  it is a short text field in my query/report. if so, how do i define it? totally new to access.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Mac1()
    Dim rsAccountNumber As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strTo As Variant
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strMessageText As String

    Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber, email_address1 FROM [P3_DVP_UnAffirmed_Report_for_En Query]", dbOpenSnapshot)

    With rsAccountNumber

        Do Until .EOF

        DoCmd.OpenReport "Unaffirmed Report", _
            acViewPreview, _
            WhereCondition:="AccountNumber = '" & !AccountNumber & "'", _
            WindowMode:=acHidden

        strTo = !Email_Address1
        strSubject = "Invoice Number "
        strMessageText = "Text Here"


        DoCmd.SendObject ObjectType:=acSendReport, _
            ObjectName:="Unaffirmed Report", _
            OutputFormat:=acFormatPDF, _
            To:=strTo, _
            Subject:=strSubject, _
            MESSAGETEXT:=strMessageText, _
            EditMessage:=True


    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Unaffirmed Report", acSaveNo


    .MoveNext

Loop

.Close

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The field `email_address1`is missing in query select. You just fetch `AccountNumber`. So add the missing field to the query. If it is not distinct then join on the base query.

Comment: Queryname seems wrong, contains spaces. If so surround with square-brackets!

Comment: query name works - i have the field in my query, would i still need to join?

Comment: Ah, you added a linebreak. Please use `_` so others can copy and paste your code. Join is only needed if `AccountNumber  ` is not distinct with the 2. field.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SELECT` list you should specify the **email_address1**  field so:

```
     Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber, email_address1 FROM [P3_DVP_UnAffirmed_Report_for_En Query]",dbOpenSnapShot)
```

Comment: ive changed to the below, but i now receive run-time error 3016: Too few parameters. Expected 1.    Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber,Email_Address1 FROM P3_DVP_UnAffirmed_Report_for_En Query")

Comment: how would i add dbOpenSnapShot?

Comment: You don't have to add dbOpenSnapShot, But if you want I edited my answer. Stick to your original syntax that worked

Comment: still get -  receive run-time error 3016: Too few parameters. Expected 1 - do i need to use a DIM for email_address1? seems like any field i use after: AccountNumber, Field just returns the same error message

Comment: No, that is a field returned from your query. For VBA to break line we use a blank and _ so I edited again my anser

Comment: still not working - now i get a: Expected list separator or ) message for the below:
Sub Mac1()
    Dim rsAccountNumber As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strTo As Variant
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strMessageText As String

Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber, Email_Address1 _
      FROM P3_DVP_UnAffirmed_Report_for_En Query", dbOpenSnapshot)

Comment: i sure do appreciate the help, but its still not working - i copied & pasted from above into my module, but i receive a 3601 - too few parameters on that line.